# Qsort doesn't sort array of pointers to strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, qsort

In this C program I read in words typed with my keyboard to a char pointer. The pointer is stored in an pointer array. Then I want to sort the array with qsort by the function comparison. I give it the pointer to my pointer array.
It doesnt sort the array at all. I dont know if I got here a UB, or I miss memory by wrong allocation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool read_word(char ***a, int *length);
int comparison(const void *p, const void *q);


int main()
{
    int *length = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *length = 0;
    char **array = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    bool go = false;

    while(go == false)
    {
        printf("Enter word: ");

        go = read_word(&array,length);
    }

    qsort(array, *length - 1,sizeof(char *), comparison);

    printf("\n");


    for(int i = 0; i < *length; i++)
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);

    return 0;
}

bool read_word(char ***a, int *length)
{
    char ch;

    ++*length;

    char *word = malloc(20 * sizeof(char) + 1);
    char *keep_word;

    char **temp = realloc(*a,*length * sizeof(*a));

    if(!temp)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    *a = temp;

    keep_word = word;

    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
        *keep_word++ = ch;

    *keep_word = '\0';

    if(word == keep_word)
    {
        free(word);
        --*length;
        return true;
    }



    (*a)[*length - 1] = word;

    printf("%s", (*a)[*length -1]);
    printf("\nh\n");
    return false;
}

int comparison(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    const char *p1 = p;
    const char *q1 = q;


    return strcmp(p1,q1);
}
```

Comment: Please tag your language, I'm not proficient enough to determine whether it's C or C++, so I won't do it for you..

Comment: Tagged. I use C in here.

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
int length = 0;//no need malloc
char **array = NULL;//first value is NULL

qsort(array, length, sizeof(char *), comparison);//not length-1

int ch;//type of return value of getchar is int

for(int i = 0; i < 20 &&  (ch = getchar()) != '\n'; ++i)//i : guard

const char *p1 = *(const char **)p;//qsort pass pointer to object to comparison function  
const char *q1 = *(const char **)q;//if char *, char **
```

Comment: `go = read_word(&array,length);` --> `go = read_word(&array, &length);`, `i < *length` --> `i < length`

Comment: Or `const char *p1 = *(char * const *)p;`

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
keep_word = word;
```

and later

```
if(word == keep_word)
```

The condition in brackets is always true.

On a side note, your program is error-prone and hard to understand because you use pointers way too much.  In `main()`, `length` should be `int`, not `int*`, array should be `char*`, not `char**` .  In the `read_word`, `a` should be `char**`, not `char***`.  Don't use pointers unless necessary!

Comment: word != keep_word, if there are chars before a '\n', cause keep_word is in a diff location then
and i use **char because its a pointer to a pointer, any other ideas how to malloc a pointer array? was only one i got on my mind :p

Comment: Wrong. In your code, `word==keep_word` ALWAYS.  If you do `foo=bar`, then `foo==bar` ALWAYS unless you change the value of `foo` or `bar` later.  You don't change the value of `word` or `keep_word`, you change the values in the memory where they point.  As for the later, does array contain many words or just one word? If it contains just one word, it should be pointer to char, not pointer to pointer.

Comment: You can specify strcmp as the comparison function to qsort.